# Loading huge csv file using COPY

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am loading CSV file using COPY.

```
COPY cts FROM 'C:\...\cts.csv' using DELIMITERS',';
```

However, error comes out

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: "" 
CONTEXT:  COPY testdata, line 7, column latitude: ""
```

How to fix it please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your CSV isn't quite formatted correctly. "" isn't a number, and numbers don't need to be be quoted in CSV.

I find it's usually easier in PostgreSQL to create a staging import table with all text columns, and import CSVs to there first. Then do a cleanup query to put the CSV data into the real table.

Comment: WOW, thanks for your reply. Any example I can look at please? Can I use some quick way like "force not NULL" to solve it ? It is one error in a big csv file

Comment: Thanks, I know what you means.